# How to DestroyWindow from remote thread?

Tags: c++, c, windows, multithreading, winapi

Doing some dll injection and need to destroy a certain window. However, `DestroyWindow` only works if the same thread that created the window calls it. Otherwise it fails with error 5: Access Denied.

I thought maybe I could trick it into thinking I was the creating thread by getting the thread id of it (`DWORD dwTid = GetWindowThreadProcessId`), then setting the thread id of the current thread to it: `__writefsdword(0x24, dwTid)` but it still fails with error 5, Access Denied.

After some Googling around I have yet to find an answer.

BTW: I'm aware I could send `WM_DESTROY` however, out of curiosity and the a need to solve problems I want to know how to do it with `DestroyWindow`.

Comment: Did you try posting WM_CLOSE to the window?

Comment: "BTW: I'm aware I could send WM_DESTROY however, out of curiosity and the a need to solve problems I want to know how to do it with DestroyWindow." - Including WM_CLOSE. Sorry, should have been more specific.

Comment: I am not sure what problems you need to solve that require you to do something simple and straightforward in a complicated way.  Perhaps you can explain the problem you are trying to solve and we can help you look for solutions for it?

Comment: As far as I know DestroyWindow is mostly a wrapper around SendMessage(... WM_DESTROY) ?

Comment: @Lundin `WM_DESTROY` is a notification message, `DestroyWindow()` does the work.

Comment: @Lundin this is not correct according to [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110926-00/?p=9553) article.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To call `DestroyWindow()`, you have to inject code that runs in the context of the thread that created the window.  Use `GetWindowThreadProcessId()` to get the window's owning thread ID, then install a message hook into that thread using `SetWindowsHookEx()`, and then finally post/send any message to the window.  When the hook callback receives the message, it will be running in the context of the window's thread, and thus can call `DestroyWindow()` on the window (the `HWND` is provided to the hook callback).