# Python win32gui application - trying to quit from external thread

Tags: python, multithreading, winapi, hook

I have a python application that uses a tray icon created through win32 to control a tkinter GUI. The tray icon can issue commands to the tkinter GUI (hide/show/close/etc.), but since it's in a separate thread it won't accept commands from the tkinter GUI (such as exiting the program).

I found a response here that outlines the process of accessing the tray icon's thread:
[How to DestroyWindow from remote thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45853173/how-to-destroywindow-from-remote-thread)

1. Get thread ID of the tray icon from GetWindowThreadProcessId()
2. Install a message hook with SetWindowsHookEx()
3. Use message hook to trigger the exit command on the tray icon thread

This sounds straightforward, but I am not clear on how to implement it in practice.

Step 1 is easy:

```
tid, pid = win32process.GetWindowThreadProcessId(self.hwnd)
```

Could someone provide an example/guidance on the format of steps 2 and 3, please?

Comment: Sounds much like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info). What are you ultimately trying to accomplish?

Comment: The overall goal is this: the program displays a window which the user can interact with, which is minimized to a tray icon instead of closing. The program can be closed or maximized from the tray icon (it appears in the same place as the Volume/Network icons, for example). The trouble is in my implementation with a mix of win32 and tkinter, which do not like to communicate across threads without the method outlined above. Does this help outline what I'm working on? I wanted to use tkinter since I'm familiar with it, but win32 seems to be needed for the tray icon.

Comment: [SendMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendmessage) and [PostMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-postmessagew) work across threads. Simply send or post a message to the application window so that it can shut down. The messages are dispatched on the thread that owns the window, so everything works out.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Searched around some more and found an example that worked like you described. Specific code was just:     win32gui.PostMessage(self.hwnd, win32con.WM_CLOSE, 0, 0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution as suggested by IInspectable in the comments was to directly use a PostMessage like so:

```
win32gui.PostMessage(self.hwnd, win32con.WM_CLOSE, 0, 0)
```

This allowed the tkinter GUI to tell the win32 tray icon to quit without encountering thread-related access errors.